Get root Xml of provided XmlElement to facilitate .ImportNode()
I have a function that accepts an [xmlNode] $testElement and an [xmlNode] $seedElement from a different XmlDocument. Under certain conditions I want to replace the $testElement with the $seedElement. To do that I need to import the $seedElement into the DocumentElement of the '$testElement. And to do that I need to GET that DocumentElement`.
This seems to work
$workingElement = $testElement
if ($workingElement.ParentNode.Name -ne '#Document') {
    do {
        $workingElement = $workingElement.ParentNode                   
        if ($workingElement.ParentNode.Name -eq '#Document') {
            $documentElement = $workingElement
        }
    } while (-not $documentElement)
}

in that the Write-Host "$($documentElement.LocalName) $($documentElement.GetType())" correctly returns #document as the name and Xml as the type. However
$replacementElement = $documentElement.ImportNode($seedElement, $true)

results in this exception

Cannot convert argument "0", with value:
"System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection1[System.Management.Automation.PSObject]", for "ImportNode" to type "System.Xml.XmlNode": "Cannot convert the "System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection1[System.Management.Automation.PSObject]"
value of type
"System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[[System.Management.Automation.PSObject,
System.Management.Automation, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]" to type "System.Xml.XmlNode"."

So obviously I NOT actually getting the Root object I need to import into. I could pass that into the function as well, but I am wondering what is going on here and why what I am trying is not working.
EDIT: I figured there must be a more direct way to get to the root.  But still seeing problems, which I am sure means I misunderstood @mclayton's comment. What I tried is
$ownerDocument = $testElement.OwnerDocument
$replacementElement = $ownerDocument.ImportNode($seedElement, $true)                             
$testElement.ParentNode.ReplaceChild($replacementElement, $testElement)

Which is still throwing the same error.
EDIT: So, the issue was that I was using
$replaceElement = $validationXml.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.Where({$_.GetAttribute('type') -eq $testElement.GetAttribute('type')})

which returns a collection of one item that somehow DOES get cast when I checked the type. So it LOOKED like I was getting the expected results, until I tried using it with something that didn't cast to a useful type. However, if I just take the first and only item, like this.
$replaceElement = $validationXml.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.Where({$_.GetAttribute('type') -eq $testElement.GetAttribute('type')})[0]

It is working. But now I have a totally new problem that requires a new post. :)

You can replace your first code block with $documentElement = $testElement.OwnerDocument (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.ownerdocument?view=net-8.0#system-xml-xmlnode-ownerdocument). The error implies you’re using dotted notation to access a node (e.g. $myxml.something.something which returns a Powershell wrapper around an xml node, not a real XmlNode object, whichImportNode requires.

@mclayton I thought there must be a quicker way. Alas, I think I misunderstood. See edit in the question for what I tried.

How are you populating $seedElement? The error is saying that’s not an xml node…

I get it via .ChildElements of the element passed in. And Write-Host "??? $($testElement.GetType())" returns ??? System.Xml.XmlElement as expected.

Can you add enough code to reproduce that here via a cut&paste? I can only see a ChildNodes property, not ChildElements so I can’t repro your exact error message…

I have to walk a couple dogs, but I'll see if I can extract enough of what I am doing to make a viable standalone demonstration when I get back. With my luck I'll look a fool because doing that will expose the problem even to dufus me.

Two young rescue dogs, one is half French Bulldog, half Staffie, half angel, half demon. She is a handful to be sure. :) Put the kids on a big power generating hamster wheel?

Oops. Added a broken link then ran out of time to edit so I deleted the comment - here’s a working tio.run example… https://tio.run/##XY7BDoIwDIbvPMVCdoBEN8UrctKDF30AwsGMKibbSsYI8PRzAzTRXv7069@/bXEA0zUg5VagAefoSI6kHJWsSJwbRFvkonnJer9qtuqBFzn/IRn5Im/m824cRVT7QDqy0LNluojGGrpyVwULe4K1UwtJyh69lPquwOPp7xXu82iNIgRO7ISiV6DtWUIQdhs0mA@MZiO7qBaNvfpLCdUbQq3pIY18OfcG

you should add and accept your additional info as an answer - it will help people with similar problems by showing the green “answered” pill in search results…
